# Getting array values from user input

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to get an integer and a double value from the user using a scanner.  Im having trouble setting the values i get to the array itself. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int SIZE = 7;
        int[] arr = new int[SIZE];
        int[] arr2 = new int[SIZE];
        double[] dub = new double[SIZE];

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        PayRoll p = new PayRoll();

        for(String i: p.AccEmp()){
            System.out.println("How many hours were worked by the this employee number: " + i);
             arr = sc.nextInt();
            p.SetHRS(arr);

            System.out.println("What is the pay for this employee number: " + i);
            dub = sc.nextDouble();
            p.setPR(dub);


        }

    }

}
```

P is an instance, accEmp is an accessor from another class.
Also, i cant use Array List.

Comment: Please, use more descriptive variable names. It'll make your code easier to read for everyone, including yourself. For example, `sc` can be `input`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `arr` variable is an array of int. `Scanner.nextInt` will read and int, but not an array.

The line `arr = sc.nextInt()` won't compile. Either change `arr` to be an `int` or add the value to the array.

I believe, since you seem to be looping over employees, that you should keep a reference to the looping index and add to the array at that index :

```
for(int i = 0; i < p.accEmp().length/* or .size() if it's a list */; i++)
{
    arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

and also incorporate this within the loop, the part where you get the double values:
`dub[i]=sc.nextDouble();`